# How to show/hide anchor tag on the basis of database value

Tags: html, asp.net

[image]In my aspx page i have listview in which i have three  tags one for hotel invoice second for package third for vehicle all 3 are visible now what i want if at first time user create hotel invoice then in database its invoice type is saved next time when user open that page on the basis of invoice type only that tag should be visible like if user create hotel invoice then only hotel invoice tag should be visible and if vehicle invoice was created then only vehicle invoice tag should be visible other two should be invisible.
Can anyone help me in this issue.
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: <a href='Invoice.aspx?Enquiry_Id=<%#Eval("Enquiry_Id") %>' style="visibility:<%#Eval("InvoiceType")="Hotel"?  "hidden" :"visible" %>> color:Purple">Hotel Invoice</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="style='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Class.YourDbValue") == null ?     "display:block;": "display:none;"%>'>>"
```

Comment: i have already tried this bt this works only for true false value or i can say boolean values bt i have three values

Comment: No its not for boolean, if you see I am checking the value present in your object.. I am assuming that you will have only 1 of the 3 values in DB so use 3 <a> tags and render anyone whose value you have stored in DB

Comment: <a style='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Class.Hotel") == null ?     "display:block;": "display:none;"%>'>>" //will render if you have hotel value  same you need to do for other two so those having value will be rendered

Answer (score 0):

@AkshayRandive  I think what he means is that his InvoiceType is based on the 3 values

```
<% 
if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Class.InvoiceType") != null)
{
     <a href='Invoice.aspx?Enquiry_Id=<%#Eval("Enquiry_Id") %>'style= "display:block;">Hotel Invoice</a>
} 
%>
```

Something like this should only show Hotel Invoice when you have an existing type.

You could make the link value dynamic but you can figure that out yourself.

Comment: you both are checking for null value bt in any case i never have null value plzzzzzzzzz understand my issue

Comment: i have posted image of my aspx page that might give you some help to understand the issue if u see the first word is invoice type bt all 3 anchor tage are visible whta i want if invoice type is hotel then other 2 one should be invisible

Comment: Make an if else if and else statement and provide each of the anchor tags with the right type of invoice. My example code should tell you how to do this. If your InvoiceType can not be null in the database, then you shouldn't check for null.
example
if(invoicetype == "Hotel Invoice")
{
<a href='Invoice.aspx?Enquiry_Id=<%#Eval("Enquiry_Id") %>'style= "display:block;">Hotel Invoice</a>
}
elseif(InvoiceType == "Package Invoice")
{
//anchor tag
}